# Docker container not removing

Tags: docker

I have 2 running containers, which I doesn't run. I don't know why they runned, maybe because I pushed image to docker hub. So, when I try to stop that container, engine creates new same containers. When I try to remove containers - there are no any effect.

Comment: So docker stop does not work? How about docker rm -f <containerId>?

Comment: Check whether you have services running: `docker service ls`

Comment: 1) yes, stop does not work

2) docker service ls - "Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager."

Comment: Keep opened an `docker events` in a terminal, in other terminal do `docker em -f ID`, and see events

Comment: I mean: docker rm ... (Not em)

Comment: I've found issue. That containers was runned by swarm service tasks and my host is a worker.

Comment: Nice. Would you like to add an answer to help others in the future?